# Handling new lines in php

Tags: php, arrays, textarea, line-breaks, explode

I have form in html where user can put the text in text area. 
I save the content of text area into MySQL database (in field of type TEXT). 
Then I somewhere in my aplication I need load that text and put it into array where in each index will be one line of the text.

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="80">
Row one
Row two
Row tree
</textarea>

array (output in "php pseudocode"):
$array = array();
$array[0] = Row one;
$array[1] = Row two;
$array[2] = Row tree;
```

How I do it:
I save it to db then I load it and use:

```
$br = nl2br($string,true);
$array = explode("<br />", $br);
```

The reason why I use **nl2br** is I want to avoid problems with end of lines of the text from different platforms. I mean /n or /r/n. 
But in my solution must be an error somewhere cause it doesn't work (an array $array is empty).

Better solution would be probably somehow split it into array using explode or something like that with pattern for line breaks but here is again the problem from beginning with line breaks which I don't know how to solve (**problems with \n or \r\n**).

Can anybody give me an advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you skip the `nl2br` until you're ready to actually send the data to the client. To tackle your problem:

```
// $string = $get->data->somehow();
$array = preg_split('/\n|\r\n/', $string);
```

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Is any difference between your regexp and that in the answer?

Comment: @user1097772: Mine is shorter. :)  Other than that, not really.  There might be a _tiny_ performance difference one way or the other, but probably not enough to measure outside highly artificial conditions.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Ok thanks for explanation and useful tip :) I'll probably use the first one cause it's more human readable :) But it's nice to know more ways how to do it :)

Answer (score -1):

When you receive the input in your script *normalize the end-of-line characters* to PHP_EOL before storing the data in the data base.  This tested out correctly for me.  It's just one more step in the "filter input" process.  You may find other EOL character strings, but these are the most common.

```
<?php // RAY_temp_user109.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (!empty($_POST['t']))
{
    // NORMALIZE THE END-OF-LINE CHARACTERS
    $t = str_replace("\r\n", PHP_EOL, $_POST['t']);
    $t = str_replace("\r",   PHP_EOL, $t);
    $t = str_replace("\n",   PHP_EOL, $t);
    $a = explode(PHP_EOL, $t);
    print_r($a);
}

$form = <<<FORM
<form method="post">
<textarea name="t"></textarea>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
FORM;

echo $form;
```

Explode on PHP_EOL and skip the nol2br() part.  You can use var_dump() to see the resulting array.

Comment: PHP_EOL is pointless for text coming from arbitrary source. PHP_EOL is set to the **LOCAL** system's EOL char(s). If the text originally came from (say) Windows, and you're running on Linux, then you'll accomplish nothing because you're looking for the wrong eol chars. PHP_EOL is only useful if you do not need portability and the data will stay on the same type of OS at all times.

Comment: -1 for the attitude (even if you added a smiley to it), and for not actually showing _how_ to normalize the input.

Comment: @llmari Karonen: Thanks for your snotgram.  I was coding the solution while you were making snide remarks.  Sheesh!

Comment: OK, downvote reversed.  However, you code will not do quite what you expect on platforms where `PHP_EOL == "\r\n"`.  You may want to normalize the newlines to a single-character value like `"\n"` instead.